# SparkStreaming shut down job in case of error

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have a streaming job that runs every minute and after processing the data puts it on hdfs and a reduced form of the results into a database.

On certain occasions (rare) I have noticed that my datanode goes bad or the database stops responding due to some reason. In such a scenario the workers throw a lot of errors but the job keeps running. I want to set up a system that as soon as there is an IO or network error my job should stop. (Probably then trigger a mail so that I can look into what went wrong and restart it.)

Can the spark job be stopped from inside the worker? (`sys.exit` obviously would not work)

Answer (score 0):

There seems no feedback channel for this. I think your best bet is to use a message-based approach (e.g. by using a messaging framework) and listen to it in the app, which starts your Spark application and stop the Spark job accordingly.